# Where to get 3rd level weapon cards' capable starships?

Tags: star-trek-trexels

Does anyone know how to get 3rd level weapon cards' capable starships in Star Trek Trexels for Android? I am in battlegroup three, bought weapons cards which are marked level three, and have spent dilithium to buy the most expensive ship pack (the advanced Ship requisition tier three). However, no ship, not even the rare ones, carry level 3 cards. Do you know what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Received an in-game comm after reaching half way through battlegroup 3 that new ships with 3rd level weapon card possibility were available when on battlegroup 4 and new cards appeared but locked. Must be some kind of freemium strategy to con you into wasting resources.